# Converting an html page to binary format in python

Tags: python, html, mongodb, binary

Suppose I have these two lines:

```
c=urllib2.urlopen(myUrl)
html=c.read()
```

I'm quite new to Python and am looking for a way to transform the HTML code stored in `html` in a binary array so I could easily store in my MongoDB without worrying about the encoding of the webpage I downloaded.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pymongo driver already has methods for importing strings as binary. Following with this example:

```
import pymongo
import bson.binary

from pymonngo import MongoClient
from bson.binary import Binary

client = MongoClient()
db = client.test

db.btest.insert({ "bindata": Binary("Hello",0) })

db.btest.find_one()
```

Which gives you:

```
{u'_id': ObjectId('5582b33c268e1505371a5477'), u'bindata': Binary('Hello', 0)}
```

Or from the `mongo` shell:

```
> db.btest.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5582b33c268e1505371a5477"),
    "bindata" : BinData(0,"SGVsbG8=")
}
```

So your string has been encoded to a BSON Binary type now in your document.

Note that it's always encoded bytes and not raw because that is how the BSON spec does it.

Answer (score 2):

As far as i remember

`c.read()`

is a normal string (hit me if i am wrong)

If thats the case, this should help you:
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578291-string-to-binary/